# Return only the final result in python re.findall command

Tags: python, search, for-loop, find

I am using re.findall to locate certain words in a series of strings.

When returning the results, I only want the last result that satisfies the findall task in each string.

I've tried:

```
m = re.findall(r'([0-9]+)\s([a-z]{7,})',s)

for i,j in m:     ##separate the two elemnts
    if m == i,j   ## if the total match result was equivalent to the i,j result    
                  ## then that is fine
      return i,j
    else:         ## if the total match result is not the same as i,j then I only want the 
                  ##final result to be returned
      return (    ## Not sure what to put here to only return the final result
```

Open to completely different methods as well of returning the only or final result from the findall action.

UPDATE:

As suggested below I changed the for-loop to say:

for i in m:
  return m[-1]

And this gave me the desired result

Comment: `m[-1]` is the last match in the list..

Comment: But what are you trying to do (give input and expected output); `m == i, j` is *never* going to be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first code represents the idea I think you had

The second code is the improvement proposed by Martijn

The third and forth codes are other posibilities

Note that in each code, I considered the possibility of no match.

```
import re

s1 = """abc 5895 kilimandjaro 81 little"""

s2 = """abc 145 abcdefghuj 87 short
kim 1498 witgenstein 893 sun
oh 142 stackoverflow 89 kol  871 kutr"""

print '========= 1 ============'
for s in (s1,s2,'75 moon 56 mars 10 pluto'):
    print s
    m = re.findall(r'(\d+)\s([a-z]{7,})',s)
    print m
    for i,j in m:     ##separate the two elemnts
        if m == [(i,j)]:   ## if the total match result was equivalent to the i,j result    
                      ## then that is fine
          print  '===> ',(i,j)
        else:         ## if the total match result is not the same as i,j then I only want the 
                      ##final result to be returned
          print '===> ',m[-1]    ## Not sure what to put here to only return the final result
          break
    else:
        print '===>  No match'
    print

print '========= 2 ============'
for s in (s1,s2,'75 moon 56 mars 10 pluto'):
    print s
    m = re.findall(r'(\d+)\s([a-z]{7,})',s)
    print m
    if m:
        print '===> ',m[-1]
    else:
        print '===>  No match'
    print

print '========= 3 ============'
for s in (s1,s2,'75 moon 56 mars 10 pluto'):
    print s
    for m in re.finditer(r'(\d+)\s([a-z]{7,})|^',s):
        pass
    print m.groups()   
    print

print '========= 4 ============'
for s in (s1,s2,'75 moon 56 mars 10 pluto'):
    print s
    print re.search(r'(\d+)\s([a-z]{7,})(?!.*?\d+\s[a-z]{7,})|$',s).groups()
    print
```

result

```
========= 1 ============
abc 5895 kilimandjaro 81 little
[('5895', 'kilimandjaro')]
===>  ('5895', 'kilimandjaro')
===>  No match

abc 145 abcdefghuj 87 short
kim 1498 witgenstein 893 sun
oh 142 stackoverflow 89 kol  871 kutr
[('145', 'abcdefghuj'), ('1498', 'witgenstein'), ('142', 'stackoverflow')]
===>  ('142', 'stackoverflow')

75 moon 56 mars 10 pluto
[]
===>  No match

========= 2 ============
abc 5895 kilimandjaro 81 little
[('5895', 'kilimandjaro')]
===>  ('5895', 'kilimandjaro')

abc 145 abcdefghuj 87 short
kim 1498 witgenstein 893 sun
oh 142 stackoverflow 89 kol  871 kutr
[('145', 'abcdefghuj'), ('1498', 'witgenstein'), ('142', 'stackoverflow')]
===>  ('142', 'stackoverflow')

75 moon 56 mars 10 pluto
[]
===>  No match

========= 3 ============
abc 5895 kilimandjaro 81 little
('5895', 'kilimandjaro')

abc 145 abcdefghuj 87 short
kim 1498 witgenstein 893 sun
oh 142 stackoverflow 89 kol  871 kutr
('142', 'stackoverflow')

75 moon 56 mars 10 pluto
(None, None)

========= 4 ============
abc 5895 kilimandjaro 81 little
('5895', 'kilimandjaro')

abc 145 abcdefghuj 87 short
kim 1498 witgenstein 893 sun
oh 142 stackoverflow 89 kol  871 kutr
('145', 'abcdefghuj')

75 moon 56 mars 10 pluto
(None, None)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do, but `m[-1]` returns the last match in the list:

```
m = re.findall(r'([0-9]+)\s([a-z]{7,})',s)
return m[-1]
```